# how to re-execute the generated query from EF's output

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework. 
When I review the T-query generated by Entity Framework, it shows a comment-out line for parameter with assigned type and value information, eg.

```
-- p__linq__0: 'ABC' (Type = String, Size = 100) .
```

I am trying to re-execute these generated T-query. Is there a way/tool to do so? Currently, I have to manually update T-query in order to execute it in SSMS .

[original generated text from EF]

```
SELECT [Books].[BookId] AS [BookId]
FROM [dbo].[Books]
WHERE [dbo].[Books].[Name] = @p__linq__0

-- p__linq__0: 'ABC' (Type = String, Size = 100)
```

[after manually re-format]

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 nvarchar(100)
SET @p__linq__0 = 'ABC'

SELECT [Books].[BookId] AS [BookId]
FROM [dbo].[Books]
WHERE [dbo].[Books].[Name] = @p__linq__0
```

Comment: When I am debugging the generated SQL I manually replace the parameters. I just paste the values rather than the hassle of creating DECLARE and SET. i.e. `WHERE [dbo].[Books].[Name] = 'ABC'`

Comment: Why do you need to re-execute the queries generated? Usually, simply writing the same IQueryable should achieve that, but I don't see the purpose of that. Keep in mind with EF you shouldn't worry too much about executing SQL or DAL stuff in general.

Comment: @Steve - it would work for a few parameters, but that's still a manual job. It would not work well if I have many parameters (10 or more ?). Also, keep the parameter variable would help me when I want to execute the same query with different input values.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro - we kept the EF generated query in the log when exception occurred. When troubleshooting, it's much easier to execute the T-query in SSMS than trying to get the exact inputs, run the application (web app) and get the same EF code execute.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro - Also, maybe it's just me, sometimes it's easier for me to exam/see the result data in the table format in SSMS than trying to check the values from EF object in the Visual Studio during the debugging mode.

Comment: I don't think those were ever intended to be continually rerun - simply there to troubleshoot. Maybe you should look for a different tool like [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/).